# Git: is it possible to use number to add(or diff) file on stage?

Tags: git

What I want to do is,

```
(spacegraphy) Chois@Chois-MacPro spacegraphy-project $ (feature/carts)git status
On branch feature/carts
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   spacegraphy/carts/tests/test_views.py
        modified:   spacegraphy/carts/views/cart.py
        modified:   spacegraphy/functional_tests/test_cartitem_at_product_detail.py
        modified:   spacegraphy/products/static/js/product_detail.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I want to see difference of `spacegraphy/carts/views/cart.py`, I want to type like this:
`>> git diff 2`
(`2` because `spacegraphy/carts/views/cart.py` is second in the unstaged file list)

Likewise, When I want to add `spacegraphy/products/static/js/product_detail.js`, I want to type like this:
`>> git add 4`

Would it be possible? Any idea please?

Comment: yes it's possible but you will have to write your own shell script which parses the output of `git status` and finds the position of the file that you want to add and then perform `git add` on that file. You can try to use `git status`, `xargs` and `git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there actually is. Check out git's [interactive staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) You will get a menu which is based on numbers.

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb

*** Commands ***
  1: status     2: update      3: revert     4: add untracked
  5: patch      6: diff        7: quit       8: help
What now>
```

So to diff a file. You would first write `6` to enter diff. Then a list of files will appear that have changes, each with a number. Type the number of the file you want to diff, for example `1`. This will output the diff, and you'll get back to the first menu.

Comment: I find something strange... I have to add all `unstaged files` first to show `diff`... Why is it like that? Does `diff` shows difference between `unstaged files` and last commit?....